# Elasticsearch Nested Filters being inclusive vs. exclusive

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an object mapping that uses nested objects (`props` in our example) in a tag-like fashion.
Each tag can belong to a client/user and when we want to allow our users to generate `query_string` style searches against the `props.name`.

Issue is that when we run our query if an object has multiple props and if one of the many props match the filter when others don't the object is returned, when we want the opposite - if one returns false don't return vs. if one returns true return.

I have posted a comprehensive example here: https://gist.github.com/d2kagw/1c9d4ef486b7a2450d95

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cant understand you problem.Can you please post more detail and also post the reason that why you are using query String Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe here you might need the advantage of a flattened list of values, like an array of values. The major difference between an array and nested objects is that the latter "knows" which value of a nested property corresponds to another value of another property in the **same** nested object. The array of values, on the other hand will flatten the values of a certain property and you lose the "association" between a `client_id` and a `name`. Meaning, with arrays you have `props.client_id = [null, 2]` and `props.name = ["petlover", "premiumshopper"]`.

With your `nested` filter you want to match that string to all values for `props.name` meaning **ALL** nested `props.name`s of one parent doc needs to match. Well, this doesn't happen with nested objects, because the nested documents are separate and are queried separately. And, if at least one nested document matches then it's considered a match.

In other words, for a query like `"query": "props.name:(carlover NOT petlover)"` you basically need to run it against a flattened list of values, just like arrays. You need that query ran against ["carlover", "petlover"].

My suggestion for you is to make your nested documents `"include_in_parent": true` (meaning, keep in parent a flattened, array-like list of values) and change a bit the queries:

- for the `query_string` part, use the flattened properties approach to be able to match your query for a combined list of elements, not element by element.
- for the `match` (or `term`, see below) and `missing` parts use the nested properties approach because you can have `null`s in there. A `missing` on an array will match only if the whole array is missing, not one value in it, so here one cannot use the same approach as for the query, where the values were flattened in an array.
- optional, but for the `query` `match` integer I would use `term`, as it's not string but integer and is by default `not_analyzed`.

These being said, with the above changes, these are the changes:

```
{
  "mappings" : {
    ...
        "props": {
          "type": "nested",
          "include_in_parent": true,
   ...
```

1. should (and does) return zero results

```
GET /nesting-test/_search?pretty=true
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "query": {
              "query_string": { "query": "props.name:((carlover AND premiumshopper) NOT petlover)" }
            }
          },
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "props",
              "filter": {
                "or": [ { "query": { "match": { "props.client_id": 1 } } }, { "missing": { "field": "props.client_id" } } ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. should (and does) return just 1

```
GET /nesting-test/_search?pretty=true
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {"query": {"query_string": { "query": "props.name:(carlover NOT petlover)" } } },
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "props",
              "filter": {
                "or": [{ "query": { "match": { "props.client_id": 1 } } },{ "missing": { "field": "props.client_id" } } ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

3. should (and does) return just 2

```
GET /nesting-test/_search?pretty=true
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          { "query": {"query_string": { "query": "props.name:(* NOT carlover)" } } },
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "props",
              "filter": {
                "or": [{ "query": { "term": { "props.client_id": 1 } } },{ "missing": { "field": "props.client_id" } }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated Andrei.