# How to query for two fields in one and the same tuple in an array in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say there are some documents in my index which look like this:

```
{
  "category":"2020",
  "properties":[
    {
     "name":"foo",
     "value":"2"
    },
    {
     "name":"boo",
     "value":"2"
    }
  ]
},
{     
  "category":"2020",
  "properties":[
    {
     "name":"foo",
     "value":"8"
    },
    {
     "name":"boo",
     "value":"2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to query the index in a way to return only those documents that match `"foo":"2"`but not `"boo":"2"`.

I tried to write a query that matches both `properties.name` *and* `properties.value`, but then I'm getting false positives. I need a way to tell ElasticSearch that name and value have to be part of the *same* properties tuple.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to map `properties` as a [`nested`type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html). So your mapping would look similar to this:

```
{
  "your_type": {
    "properties": {
      "category": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "properties": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, your query to match documents having `"foo=2"` in the same tuple but not `"boo=2"` in the same tuple would need to use the [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) accordingly, like the one below.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "properties",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "properties.name": "foo"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "properties.value": "2"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "properties",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "properties.name": "boo"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "properties.value": "2"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Val's answer is as good as it gets. One thing I would add, though, since it makes the difference between one type of query and others that might benefit from `nested`s "opposite" feature.

In Elasticsearch, the default type for `"properties":[{"name":"foo","value":"2"},{"name":"boo","value":"2"}]` that is used to auto-create such a field is `object`. The `object` has the drawback that it doesn't associate one sub-field's value with another sub-field's value, meaning `foo` is not necessarily associated with `2`. `name` is just an array of values and `value` is the again another array of values with not association between the two.

If one needs the above association to work then `nested` is a must.

But, I have encountered situations where both these features were needed. If you need both of these, you can set [`include_in_parent: true` for the mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-nested-type.html#_mapping) so that you can take advantage of both. One of the situations that I have seen is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666037/elasticsearch-nested-filters-being-inclusive-vs-exclusive).

```
"properties": {
    "type": "nested",
    "include_in_parent": true,
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
    ...
```