# Querying multiple nested objects in elasticsearch for prescene of one and non prescence of another across all the nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

Running on elasticsearch 2.3

I have an index of foos.  Each foo has 0 or more bars that are stored in a nested object.  Each bar has 0 or more properties with a name and a value.

Using the docs at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html

It's been pretty straightforward to write queries to:

- return all foos that have at least 1 `bar.name = "sandwich"` OR
- return all foos that don't have a `bar.name = "pizza"`

What I don't seem to be able to figure out is how to write a query that returns all foos that:

- have at least 1 `bar.name = "sandwich"` AND
- have no `bar.name = "pizza"`

Been banging my head against this one for longer than I care to admit.  Any help appreciated.

Details:

A foo has 2 properties:

- `foo_id`: a number
- `bar` : a list of 0 or more bars, stored as nested documents

A bar has 2 properties:

- `bar_id`: a number
- `properties`: a list of 0 or more kv pairs.

Stripped down mapping.  The real program has nothing to do with food.

```
{
  "some_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "foo" : {
        "properties" : {
          "bar" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "bar_id" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "details" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "value" : {
                    "type" : "long"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "foo_id" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "store" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Typical foo with no pizza

```
# this one does have a bar.name = sandwich
# this one doesn't have pizza for ANY bars
# this would match the query
{
        "foo_id": 186456,
        "bar": [
        {
                "bar_id": 1056791,
                        "details": [
                        {
                                "name": "taco",
                                "value": 2
                        },
                        {
                                "name": "sandwich",
                                "value": 1
                        }
                ]
        },
        {
                "bar_id": 1056800,
                "details": [
                {
                        "name": "sandwich",
                        "value": 0
                }
                ]
        }
        ]

}
```

Typical foo with some pizza

```
# this one has a bar.name = sandwich
# this one has pizza for some bars, but not all of them
# this would NOT match the query
    {
            "foo_id": 187390,
            "bar": [
            {
                    "bar_id": 1057455,
                            "details": [
                            {
                                    "name": "taco",
                                    "value": 1
                            }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "bar_id": 1057457,
                    "details": [
                    {
                            "name": "taco",
                            "value": 0
                    },
                    {
                            "name": "sandwich",
                            "value": 1
                    }
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "bar_id": 1057458,
                    "details": [
                    {
                            "name": "sandwich",
                            "value": 1
                    },
                    {
                            "name": "pizza",
                            "value": 0
                    }
                    ]
            }
            ]

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `bar` field to `include_in_parent` be `true`:

```
    "bar": {
      "type": "nested",
      "include_in_parent": true, 
      "properties": {
        "bar_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "details": {
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And use this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "bar.details.name:(sandwich NOT pizza)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are officially my hero.  Last time I did anything serious with es queries was 0.9 and somehow I missed that pouring through all the changes.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries :-) and I'm glad I was able to help you, these things are a bit tricky. Your requirement was very similar with something I dealt with in the past, so it was kind of easy to adapt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666037/elasticsearch-nested-filters-being-inclusive-vs-exclusive.